# Uglify, Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack

I used webpack2 to build my app, but when use uglify-js + uglifyjs-webpack-plugin.I have some problems:

```
ERROR in vendors.js from UglifyJs
TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined
at F:\Github\Program\My-test\Webpack\www2\node_modules\_uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.3@uglifyjs-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:99:22
at F:\Github\Program\My-test\Webpack\www2\node_modules\_uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.3@uglifyjs-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:231:9
at Array.forEach (native)
at Compilation.<anonymous> (F:\Github\Program\My-test\Webpack\www2\node_modules\_uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.3@uglifyjs-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:54:19)
at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (F:\Github\Program\My-test\Webpack\www2\node_modules\_tapable@0.2.6@tapable\lib\Tapable.js:142:13)
at self.applyPluginsAsync.err (F:\Github\Program\My-test\Webpack\www2\node_modules\_webpack@2.5.1@webpack\lib\Compilation.js:635:10)
at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (F:\Github\Program\My-test\Webpack\www2\node_modules\_tapable@0.2.6@tapable\lib\Tapable.js:131:46)
at sealPart2 (F:\Github\Program\My-test\Webpack\www2\node_modules\_webpack@2.5.1@webpack\lib\Compilation.js:631:9)
at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (F:\Github\Program\My-test\Webpack\www2\node_modules\_tapable@0.2.6@tapable\lib\Tapable.js:131:46)
at Compilation.seal (F:\Github\Program\My-test\Webpack\www2\node_modules\_webpack@2.5.1@webpack\lib\Compilation.js:579:8)
at F:\Github\Program\My-test\Webpack\www2\node_modules\_webpack@2.5.1@webpack\lib\Compiler.js:493:16
at F:\Github\Program\My-test\Webpack\www2\node_modules\_tapable@0.2.6@tapable\lib\Tapable.js:225:11
at _addModuleChain (F:\Github\Program\My-test\Webpack\www2\node_modules\_webpack@2.5.1@webpack\lib\Compilation.js:481:11)
at processModuleDependencies.err (F:\Github\Program\My-test\Webpack\www2\node_modules\_webpack@2.5.1@webpack\lib\Compilation.js:452:13)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

The webpack config maybe give some help to you:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: path.resolve(APP, 'index.js'),
        vendors: ['jquery', 'moment']
    },
    output: {
        path: BUILD,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HTMLwebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Generate by webpack'
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendors',
            filename: 'vendors.js'
        }),
        new UglifyJSPlugin({
            compress: true
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: 'style-loader!css-loader?sourceMap!sass-loader?sourceMap',
                include: APP 
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
                loaders: 'url-loader?limit=40000'
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/, 
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: APP,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', {"modules": false}]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: 'eval-source-map'
}
```

What's the 'reset' mean? I can't find answer in anywhere...
Thanks!

Comment: Send your index.js at F:\Github\Program\My-test\Webpack\www2\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js

Comment: I had the same problem. As a workaround: Install 3.0.0 instead of 3.0.3 and the probem will go away for now...

Comment: This is issue of Webpack 2 and UglifyJS 3. Just use UglifyJS 2.8 with Webpack 2.

Answer (score 17):

**Edit august 2017:**
Now uglifyjs-webpack-plugin [works with uglify-js@3](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin)

Install the plugin: `npm install uglifyjs-webpack-plugin --save-dev`, then, in webpack config:

```
var UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')
...
plugins: [
    new UglifyJSPlugin()
]
```

Answer (score 4):

works for me:

```
  npm install uglifyjs-webpack-plugin --save-dev

 plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
]
```

But this is not  work:

```
  new UglifyJSPlugin({
        compress: true
    })
```

Same question was at Github, the answer was :

> Currently using UglifyJS 3 breaks the plugin. It has a new API so the plugin has to change accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

I only did this to solve it:

```
npm install --save-dev uglify-js@2
```

You have to make sure you're using uglify 2 and not 3.
My config looks like this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Its working with webpack3 + angular4 just use 
`npm install uglify-js@2.8.27 --save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

**2017-07-26**

I solved the issue by:

`npm i -D uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1.0.0-beta.2`

Reason: `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.x`, which is the version used by `webpack`, does not support uglify-js 3. Since `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1.0.0-beta`, it starts supporting uglify-js 3.

Reference:

1. https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/issues/32
2. https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/pull/63